# Preserve sort order of SOAP result

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I've built a SOAP service with JAX-WS, and it returns a number of sorted results, that are basically sorted in the order the customer finds aesthetically pleasing. I've got this handled no problem in my back end, and the results are coming through consistently in the right order. Now the client piece, being generated by wsimport, is using ArrayLists when it receives these results, which are not guaranteed to preserve order when iterated. Is there any way to override this? Or even better something I can do on the SOAP side in the schema that will tell any client that it needs to preserve the order??
( cause I just KNOW I'm going to have to do a C# client for this soon )

tia!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is using ArrayLists when it receives these results, which are not guaranteed to preserve order when iterated.

Where does this assumption come from?

The [`java.util.List` interface represents an **ordered** collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). The order of elements in the collection is essential. Any implementation of `java.util.List` which did not return the correct order of the elements in the collection when iterating would be breaking the contract of the interface.

[The Javadoc for the `List.iterator()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29) method states (emphasis mine):

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in **proper** sequence.

The iterator returned by ArrayList does not violate this. It returns elements to you in the same order as the underlying array.